# Assembly Language x8086 - Passing Parameters

Tags: assembly, parameter-passing, procedure

I am in need of some help on figuring it out how to pass my variables that I've declared as parameters. My professor doesn't explain it well at all and when I ask him a question he just tells me to read the book, but the questions I have are because I don't fully understand the book.

Well basically, in this homework assignment I have to pass parameters into my procedures such as passing  my variables: userMsg, printSum, sumMessage, printW, wMessage, etc. I am currently clueless as to how to start off.

I am not sure how to pass a String as a parameter so when another person who looks at my code can modify the variable names in the main procedure and in the declarations and have the program run perfectly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

Y dw ? 
W dw ?
Sum dw ?   
Space db ,0ah, '$'
userMsg db "Please enter your number: ", '$'   
printSum db "The Sum is: ",  
sumMessage db 0,0,0,0,0     ,0dh, 0ah
printW db "W is: " 
wMessage db 0,0,0,0,0   ,0dh, 0ah, '$'  


.code
main proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax   


call getInput 
    call calcInput
call modifySum    
call displaySum

mov ax,4C00h
int 21h

main endp 




;getInput procedure
getInput proc


mov si, 0
mov cx, 100

yLoop:                              ;Loop to print message asking user to input number
    mov al, 0
    mov al, userMsg[si]
    inc si 
    cmp al, '$'
    je endY
    mov dl, al   
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h  

loop yLoop  

endY: 
    mov si, 0
    mov cx, 0

    mov     cx, 10
    mov     bx, 0  
loop1:
    mov     ah,1h
    int     21h   
    cmp     al,0dh 
    je      endloop  
    sub al, 30h
    mov ah, 0h
    mov si, ax
    mov ax, bx   
    mul cx
    mov bx, ax
    add bx,si
    jmp     loop1
endloop: 


ret   

getInput endp 


;calcInput procedure
calcInput proc

mov Y, bx

mov ax,Y     ;Store Y in ax register
sub ax,1
mov Y, ax
mov ax, 0

mov Sum,36         ; add 36 to Sum
mov bx,Y
add Sum,bx         ; add 36 and Y into Sum
mov ax,Y

mov bx,4            ; take Y and divide by 4
mov dx,0
idiv bx
add Sum,ax  

mov ax,Y           ;take Y and divide by 100
mov bx,100
mov dx,0
idiv bx
add Sum,ax  

mov bx,7
mov dx,0                        ; calculate W
idiv bx
mov W,dx
add W,1
mov dx, W 

ret             


calcInput endp   


;modifySum procedure
modifySum proc


add dl, 30h
mov wMessage+1, dl  

mov ax, 0
mov dx, 0 
mov ax,Sum  
mov cx, 10            ;start modding the number 2553
idiv cx   

mov si, 4

sumLoop:                   ;Loop to mod and store 2553 into sumMessage
     add dl, 30h
     mov sumMessage+[si], dl 
     mov dx, 0 
     mov cx, 10 
     idiv cx
     dec si   
     cmp si, 0h
     je endSum

loop sumLoop  

endSum: 

mov si, 1

removeZero:                 ;Locate zeros

    cmp sumMessage+[si], 30h
    je useSpace  
    jmp endRemove

loop removeZero              

useSpace:                       ;Replace leading zeros with a blank space

    mov sumMessage+[si], 20h 
    inc si
    jmp removeZero


loop useSpace 

endRemove:

ret           

modifySum endp  


;displaySum procedure
displaySum proc


mov ax, 0               ;Print a newline after user input
mov dl, Space
mov ah, 2h
int 21h 




mov si, 0
mov cl, printSum

L1:                              ;Loop to print out "Sum is : 2553
    mov al, 0
    mov al, printSum[si]
    inc si 
    cmp al, '$'
    je end_loop
    mov dl, al   
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h  

loop L1:  

end_loop:

ret   


displaySum endp

end main
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: be patient and read books )) . [check this](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH11/CH11-1.html)

Comment: [**The Art of Assembly Language Check chapter 11**](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~pannain/mc404/aulas/pdfs/Art%20Of%20Intel%20x86%20Assembly.pdf)

Comment: write a simple C function that calls your function, compile to object (-c option usually or /c) and then disassemble that and see exactly how and where the compiler is putting the passed parameters.  then apply that to what the book is doing, same goes on the receiving end, make a dummy function that adds the parameters together or something simple.  use the same compiler that you are going to use with your asm task of course as the calling conventions can vary from one to another

Comment: @rcgldr surely you mean `push bp` not `push sp` to start our stack frame.

Comment: The "standard" call convention is to push the parameters (or their addresses) onto the stack. If this was a C program, then the parameters are pushed in order from right to left. At program entry, sp will point to the return address, but it can't be used as a base register for addressing, so its' common to start with | push bp | mov bp,sp | and then use bp. After this, the return address is at 2[bp], the first parameter at 4[bp], second parameter at 6[bp],

Comment: @FrankKotler - recommented with the fix to show push bp .

Comment: @rcgldr Could you provide an example using a variable that contains a string and one that contains a value? I am still clueless after reading your answer, but I remember seeing this in my book. But I still don't have a grasp on the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Example based on your code.

```
        mov     ax, Y
        lea     bx, userMsg
        push    bx
        push    ax
        call    example  ; Y, offset userMsg
        add     sp,4
```

to display the string:

```
example proc
        push    bp                    ;save bp
        mov     bp,sp                 ;set bp = sp
;                                     ;2[bp] = return address
;                                     ;4[bp] = first parameter
;                                     ;6[bp] = second parameter
        mov     dx,6[bp]              ;display message
        mov     ah,09h
        int     21h
;       ...
        pop     bp
        ret
```

Comment: So this piece of code will go in my main procedure, but I am still confused as to how this will work with my code, since I think from what I understand that you're moving the address of the userMsg into bx, but then I have no clue as to what to put in my getInput procedure where i have to print out each character of my userMsg string.

Comment: Ohh that actually makes a lot of sense! Now if I wanted to print each character from my userMsg string individually since I believe my professor wants us to print our messages like that using the mov ah, 2h. Other than that, For the rest of my when i modify my code to process the Y variable, in my calcInput procedure do I use replace Y with a register that I've already stored Y in?